# Get the value of selected radio button in Fabrik Form using PHP

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I am new to Web development.
I have a requirement to do different processing based on the selection made in radio-button in Fabrik Form in Joomla.

I have confimed that the Form is submitted via POST using

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {return true;} else {return false;}
```

I have checked that the radio button is selected using :

```
if (isset($_POST['file_request___Action'])) {return true;} else {return false;}
```

This works fine when one of the radio buttons is selected.

Now, on the form I checked the "Print" button and then I tried to validate it using PHP :

```
switch($_POST['file_request___Action']) 
{
case "Save":           
    return false;            
    break;        
case "Print":           
    return true;            
    break;       
default:           
    return false;   
}
```

This does not work.Even if the Print button is checked it returns false.

Not sure if this is correct but I also tried using switch($_POST['file_request___Action[]'])

Can some point out where I am going wrong?
How should I access these radio buttons?

```
<div class="fabrikElement file_request___Action">
     <div class="fabrikSubElementContainer" id="file_request___Action">
        <div class="fabrik_subelement" style="float:left;width:23%">
            <label>
            <span>Save</span>
            <input class="fabrikinput" type="radio" name="file_request___Action[]" value="Save" checked="checked"> 
             </label>
        </div> <!-- end row div -->
        <div class="fabrik_subelement" style="float:left;width:23%">
            <label>
            <span>Print</span>
            <input class="fabrikinput" type="radio" name="file_request___Action[]" value="Print">
            </label>
        </div> <!-- end row div -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML extract for radio buttons :

Comment: Please post a few parts of your HTML.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos : Thank You , I have posted the html extract here.

Comment: Can I get some suggestions on the problem above please ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[]` from the `file_request___Action[]` in HTML?

Comment: I am using Fabrik and I can't change the html. I tried changing it through Fire-bug but behaviour remains the same even after making the change to the html from Fire-bug

Comment: Then please add this in your code `var_dump($_POST['file_request___Action'])` and update your question with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Fabrik allows you to access all the form data with their Form data post object. See info about that here:

http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/php-form-plugin/#accessing-form-data

You should be using the FormPHP plugin and then just do a simple check on your radio button:

```
$checkbox = $formModel->formData->tbl_name___element_name
```

Note: do a var_dump of this to get the full / proper elment name. It might be in array, and you may even need to do $checkbox[0] to get the array data. Also you might need to add _raw to the end of the element name to help get at the raw submitted data.

From there you should be able to go through your switch. Another possible way to do this is with Fabrik's automated replacement (pending where you are firing the FormPHP Plugin):

```
$radio1 = (int)"{listname___radio1_raw}";
```